# limit for number of rpms can have in yum repository

Tags: rpm

I try to find if we have some limitations for number of RPMs that yum repository can contains.

Or if we will have performance issues when repo is too big.

Comment: Yes, performance may degrade because your repomd xml files will take long time to parse and load...

Answer (score 1):

I have repositories with 80k packages. So I guess that only limit is MAXINT and size of your memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can have performance issues depending on the type of filesystem (ext2, ext3, ext4, etc) that is underneath your yum repo. If you put several thousand files in a single directory and then notice that doing an ls of the directory is painfully slow, then your yum repo will also have problems.